# Which is a more appropriate type for composition of bundles?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, pullback

I'm trying to understand and mangle pullbacks and limits/colimits into Coq.

Some of the notations are ambiguous. There are also differences of terminology I don't understand.

Which is better?

Precomposition as a bifunctor of an arrow category and an over category?

$$ (f: \mathrm{Arr} (C)) \times C/\mathrm{dom}(f) \rightarrow C/\mathrm{cod}(f)$$

Or precomposition as a bifunctor of an over category?

$$ (f: C/c) \times C/\mathrm{dom}(f) \rightarrow C/c$$

Or something else?

Also apparently you can just ignore the result of the function?
I don't get that.

$$ (x: C) \times C/x  \rightarrow C$$

Wouldn't that be something like?

$$ (f: C/1) \times C/\mathrm{dom}(f) \rightarrow C/1$$

I'm also not sure how to think of it as a bifunctor as some kind of monoid or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but just a note:

- Firstly I believe both these things work just fine in theory. Note that in the first case you are using a free $c$, that you might want to bind in your definition, doing so yields
  $$
  (c:C) \times (f:C/c)\times C/\operatorname{dom}(f) \to C/c
  $$
  And from there, you can note that
  $$
  (c : C) \times (f:C/c) \simeq (f:Arr(C))
  $$
  So both formulation are completely equivalent, at least from a logical point of view.
- There is a big caveat that I want to add though, about proof relevance and categories. You might want to be very careful about how you handle proof-relevance (and if you have sorted this already, you should tell us what your choice is). This is particularly important if you look at over categories. The morphisms in the over categories are commutative triangles. In particular, when formalizing in Coq, you would write the type of morphisms to be something like
  $$ 
  \operatorname{hom}_{C/c}(f:d\to c, f':d'\to c) = (g : d \to d') \times (f'\circ g = f) 
  $$
  If you want to reproduce usual category theory, you really don't want to take in account the witness. More precisely, what I mean is that if you have a morphism $g$ and two proofs $p : f'\circ g = f$ and $q : f'\circ g = f$, you really don't want to define $(g,p)$ and $(g,p')$ as two distinct morphisms in the over category. So you probably need to take some kind of truncation. Again you might be already doing that, but I think you should explain to us how you do it, as it might matter for the aswer you are looking for.
- In the dark, without knowing your implementation, I would think the formulation
  $$ (c:C)\times (f:C/c)\times C/\operatorname{dom}(f) \to C/c$$
  has more chances to have better computational behaviour. The reason for this is that in this case you ensures that $\operatorname{cod}(f)$ is definitionally equal to $c$, and that might save up some computation.
- I am not sure I understand your last question, you can understand the morphism
  $$ (x:C) \times C/x \to C$$
  very easily on its own. Given an object $x$ of $C$ and a morphism $f$ of codomain $x$, it returns the domain of $f$. You can also define a the precompostion of morphisms above the terminal object, as you have noted
  $$ 
  (f:C/1)\times C/\operatorname{dom}(f) \to C/1
  $$
  But there is an isomorphism $C/1\simeq C$, and under this isomoprhism, those two are the same

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess I want to understand how mathematicians most think of precomposition. Yes I have indeed run into many problems figuring out proof relevance. Currently morphisms are setoids but I'm still looking for better constructions. The actual issue I most needed setoids for was presheafs and yoneda btw.

Comment: I can tell you how I think about precomposition, and I think there are many views on that. One way to think of it is that composition is a (partial) binary composition, and precomposition is the currying of composition. Another view is the bundle view : If you have a map whose domain is a base set (index the fibers of a bundle), then you can use this map to "reindex", using the codomain set as fibers. So basically you can think of it as permuting and "squashing" the fibers

Comment: I guess I think of bundles as a generalization of subsets (monic bundles) but you end up with something gross like $(P \circ Q)(x) = Q(x) \rightarrow P(x)$ ? Precomposition is supposed to give you dependent types right? But it's confusing to think of it on subsets.

Comment: Your interpretation of bundles is too narrow, especially for going towards dependent types. Using type theory notation, the archetypal bundle is $\Sigma (x:A) B x \to A$. The way we usually think of bundles is as some sort of fibered things. Let me take an example with set to make things easier : when people say that a map $f : A\to B$ is a bundle, what they usually mean is that $f$ is a fancy way of encoding a family of sets indexed by $B$. So you can think of $f$ as equivalent to a family $(F_x)_{x\in B}$. The way the encoding works is that $F_x$ is the preimage of $x$ by $f$.

Comment: Using the interpretation of my previous comment, if you have a family $(F_x)_{x\in B}$ and a map $b : B \to C$, then you can build a family $(F'_y)_{y\in C}$ by setting, by definition $F'_y := \bigsqcup_{g(x) = y} F_x$. That is what the precomposition does in terms of bundles. It reindexes the $F$ with elements of $C$ instead of elements of $B$ and squash all those whose index are mapped onto the same thing via $g$. It is a good exercise to work out precisely why this is the composition, when viewed through the encoding of bundles as a function $f : A\to B$ as described in the previous comment

Comment: Wow feels like years later but I think I figured out a wrinkle in the above. IIRC Cat is not locally Cartesian closed. So I think precomposition ought to be interpreted as a functor consuming a dependent sum? I'm not quite sure universal quantification makes sense for functors exactly.